# Вывод значений массива через заданное время, поочередно

Tags: javascript

Нужно, чтобы значения массива выводились поочередно - каждое через 1 секунду. Как это сделать? У меня выводятся сразу все значения.

```js
let arr = [1,3,4,56,7,8,54];

    for(let i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      document.body.innerHTML += arr[i] + '<br>';
      setInterval(function(){},1000);
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const arr = [1,3,4,56,7,8,54];

for(let i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   setTimeout(function(){
       document.body.innerHTML += arr[i] + '<br>';
   }, i*1000);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ответ, приведенный выше, правильный. Однко обратите внимание, что в цикле критично объявление счетчика через let i=0. Если используете ES5 (var), то нужен обрамляющий контекст в виде самовызывающейся функции, иначе счетчик замкнется на последнее значение i.

PS. Не заметил, что в вопросе ES6. Ну да ладно, почитайте про замыкания :)

```js
var arr = [1,3,4,56,7,8,54];

for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    (function (i) {   
       setTimeout(function(){
           document.body.innerHTML += arr[i] + '<br>';
       }, i*1000);
    })(i);
}
```